# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap

Tags: c#, ssis

I made a SSIS package that would export data to msaccess. If i try to run the package on its solution project it will execute without error. But when I call the package inside my program, I will get an error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'. This assembly was compiled for a different processor.

Here is my code:

```
public void RunPackage()
    {
        textstring("Locating Package...");
        m_worker2.ReportProgress(20);
        string PkgLocation;
        Package pkg;
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application _app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application(); --> I got an exception here.
        DTSExecResult pkgResult;

        PkgLocation = Properties.Settings.Default.PackageLoc + "\"Package1.dtsx";
        textstring("Loading Package...");
        m_worker2.ReportProgress(30);
        pkg = _app.LoadPackage(PkgLocation, null);
        textstring("Executing Package...");
        m_worker2.ReportProgress(30);
        pkgResult = pkg.Execute();
        textstring("Finished...");
        m_worker2.ReportProgress(30);
        textstring(pkgResult.ToString());
        m_worker2.ReportProgress(30);
    }
```

Can anyone point me out the right way. I don't know what is meant by that error. Please enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means, that you mixed x86 and x64 architectures. If your application is x86 (=32 Bit) architecture, you can not use x64 (=64 Bit) compiled assemblies. Try to compile your application with **Any CPU** or **x64**.

From MSDN:

> To set the Platform target property (C#)
>
> 1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu,
>      click Properties.
> 2. Click the Build tab.
> 3. Choose a CPU type from the Platform target list. The options are Any
>      CPU (the default), x86, x64, and Itanium.

Here is the complete Link: [How to: Optimize an Application for a Specific CPU Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/5b4eyb0k(v=vs.100).aspx)

Important: if you compile for x64 and use x64 assemblies, your application will not run under 32-Bit versions of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I recently upgraded to SQL 2016 and my VB app stopped running my package.  I saved the package no problem to SQL 2016.  VB wouldn't run it via the LoadFromSqlServer method.  Just reported Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap'  What fixed it for me was to delete the old 12.0 manageddts reference and adding the new 13.0 reference  (see image)
[image]

Comment: Note, this fix only works for me when I run on a box that has sql 2016 installed.  When I ran the code on a sql 2014 box it started bombing again.  From what I've read SSIS SSDT is not backwards compatible.  Once you move it to a new version of SQL then there is no going back.

Comment: also note, I did try the target platform discussed above and after many hours concluded I wasn't going to get it to work...changing the target to SQL 2014 and then saving the package to SQL 2014 didn't work for me.  The package would fail when run from VB which was probably the VB apps fault (maybe bad reference?) as I could get the package to run from command prompt and from SSDT Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Hello there, @Tom McDonald, The image/picture you posted above is form which file? Can you please help? I'm facing similar issue but for 'Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

Comment: I'm able to see it using Chrome.  Give another browser a try.

Comment: Thank you Tom for quick reply. I am using Chrome and I can see the image. Just curious  to now, if I have to fix this issue, which file I have to modify? Any pointers?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your version of SQL Server Data Tools that is installed on your  system, you must add a specific version of `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap` in your `C#`  Application.

For example if you have SQL Server Data Tools 2010 installed you must add `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap 11.0.0.0`, and for  SQL Server Data Tools 2012 
you must add `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap 12.0.0.0`